# Оптимальная визуализация клеточного автомата в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, svg, оптимизация, рисование

Пишу игру жизнь с динамическим интерфейсом (чтобы можно было приближать/отдалять разные участки поля, менять цвет клетки).

Canvas буду использовать в крайнем случае из-за сложности вычисления координат и т.д.

Сначала была идея создавать поле из квадратов в svg а потом динамически менять цвет. Работает, но из-за огромного количества элементов вся страница начинает лагать.

Можно ли как-то оптимизировать svg, и возможно есть еще какие-то более оптимальные варианты?

Comment: Если все операции выполнять в массиве массивов, а canvas использовать только для отображения квадратиков... всё еще остаются 'сложности вычисления координат' ?)

Comment: Вряд-ли у вас получится оптимизировать SVG, для таких целей и был придуман Canvas. В связи с большим количеством HTML элементов страница не может обрабатываться должным образом и начнет лагать, и оптимизировать это можно лишь уменьшив количество элементов. Для создания игр воспользуйтесь ThreeJS или другим фреймворком для создания игр, благо их с лихвой.

Comment: @MoloF канвас очень долго загружается(